# Create a Data frame with one line and Null Values on R

Tags: r, dataframe, null

I would like to create a dataframe with a single line with NULL values for the columns "Date", "p.value" and "User", but I'm not suceeding with the code below:

```r
df <- data.frame(Date=NULL, "p.value"=NULL, User=NULL)
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: do you mean you want a column, with the name "DATE", and underneath it (on row 1) for it to be written NULL?

Comment: When I need a 0-row frame, I tend to use correct-class objects and then `[0,]`-subset it. E.g., `data.frame(Date = Sys.Date(), p.value = 0, User = "")[0,]`. With this, if I will be combining it with other data and/or doing other similar things that are class-sensitive, it will not err for that reason. (This is close to AndrewGB's use of `character()`, though I don't know if we have as-direct a mechanism such as `as.Date()` (which does not work).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an empty dataframe, you can initialize a vector with the class (e.g., `character`). If you are needing a date format, then you can wrap `as.Date` around `character`.

```
df <- data.frame(Date=as.Date(character()),
                 "p.value"=character(), 
                 User=character(), 
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#[1] Date    p.value User   
#<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Or you could use `NA` if you need an actual row. But this defaults to logical for class. So, if you need columns to be a particular class, then you would still need to wrap the class around the `NA` (e.g., `as.character(NA)`).

```
df <- data.frame(Date=NA, "p.value"=NA, User=NA, 
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#  Date p.value User
#1   NA      NA   NA
```

You can use `NULL` as character, but I don't think it's possible to have only a `NULL` row.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work too:

`example_df <- data.frame( "date" = character(0), "p.value" = integer(0), "USER" = integer(0))`

Comes up with this:

[1] date    p.value USER
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)